# How to apply a double centralizer property on a faithful module of a self-injective Artin algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let all considered algebras be Artin algebras and let all considered modules be finitely generated.

Let $A$ be left-QF-3 with minimal faithful left ideal $Ae$. Then the following are equivalent:

$\bullet$ $Ae$-dom.dim.$(A)\geq 2$

$\bullet$ There holds a double centralizer property $A=\text{End}(Ae_{eAe})$

(This is theorem 2.10 of http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930098726X#).

Corollary 2.11 of the same paper states:

Let $A$ be a self-injectie algebra, let $M$ be a faithful
$A$-module, and let $B:=\text{End}_A(M)$. Then there is a double centralizer property $A=\text{End}(M_B)$.

The proof of 2.11 shows that dom.dim.($B$)$\geq 2$.

Now my question is:

> How to apply 2.10 in order to show 2.11?

It seems that the $M$ in 2.11 is the $Ae$ in 2.10. But why is $M$ projective? and must $M$ be a minimal faithful projective module?

Thanks for the help.